# Vue - Destructuring object to this (data)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, destructuring

How can I use object destructuring to my Vue component data?
This is my actual code:

```
data: () => ({
  descricao: '',
  perfilBase: null,
  anotherField: '',
  otherOne: false
}),

mounted () {
  this.descricao = this.$route.query.descricao
  this.perfilBase = this.$route.query.perfilBase
}
```

How can I do it like this? Is it possible?

```
mounted () {
  { this.descricao, this.perfilBase } = ...this.$route.query
}
```

Comment: Try to remove '...'  in front of this.$route.query

Answer (score 5):

To use destructuring with targets other than simple variables, you cannot use the shorthand syntax but need to specify the destructured property name explicitly. In your case:

```
mounted () {
  ({ descricao: this.descricao, perfilBase: this.perfilBase } = this.$route.query);
}
```

However, if the `query` object contains only those two properties, `Object.assign` is a much simpler solution:

```
mounted () {
  Object.assign(this, this.$route.query);
}
```

Comment: I think the first example becomes useful when changing from one case style to another, like this: `({ order_number: this.orderNumber, order_amount: this.orderAmount } = this.config);`

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a way to be as succinct as you want to be.

The best thing you can do is probably

```
mounted () {
   const { descricao, perfilBase } = this.$route.query
   this.descricao = descricao
   this.perfilBase = perfilBase
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if this works, i am not behind my computer right now.

```
{ a, b } = this.$route;
[ this.a, this.b ] = [a, b];
```

Comment: This really works, i verified it.

Comment: I have to declare to make this work, on chrome.  `const { a, b } = this.$route;`

Comment: Yes you are right @JamieMarshall

Comment: It's two lines instead of one, but the array syntax prevents you from writing an assignment for every property extracted.

Comment: @GiorgioTempesta technically the first line can be combined with the second line like this ```[this.a, this.b] = [this.$route.a, this.$route.b]``` but i prefer the 2 lined version

Comment: @yooneskh yes I totally agree: more clarity and also (slightly) less typing